# After Update Trigger will not update - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**This question is for SQL Server 2008:**

I am not able to set SyncRequired = 1, when I update any of the fields below.

I am sure it's something very simple that I am missing, but I cannot figure it out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [core].[updCustomersSync] ON [core].[Customers]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF ( UPDATE(Addr1)
         OR UPDATE(Addr2)
         OR UPDATE(Addr3)
         OR UPDATE(Zip)
         OR UPDATE(Contact1)
         OR UPDATE(Phone1)
         OR UPDATE(email)
         OR UPDATE(CustomerName)
       ) 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  c
            SET     c.SyncRequired = 1
            FROM    core.Customers c
                    JOIN inserted ins ON ins.ID = c.ID
            WHERE   c.[CustomerName] <> ins.[CustomerName]
                    OR c.[Addr1] <> ins.[Addr1]
                    OR c.[Addr2] <> ins.[Addr2]
                    OR c.[Addr3] <> ins.[Addr3]
                    OR c.[Zip] <> ins.[Zip]
                    OR c.[Contact1] <> ins.[Contact1]
                    OR c.[Phone1] <> ins.[Phone1]
                    OR c.[email] <> ins.[email]
        END
```

Comment: Just a typo when I changed the table names for the post

Comment: You are not checking for NULLs.  That may be an issue.  If a column is updated from NULL to non-NULL (or vice-versa) the trigger won't work.

Comment: But the existing values are not null.....

Comment: Try checking INSERTED vs DELETED.

Comment: [INSERTED vs DELETED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) -- these are special tables in SQL Server that exist for DML triggers.

Comment: In addition to using `deleted` instead of `inserted` (or using an `instead of` trigger instead), so that you're comparing the old copy of the row to the new instead of the new copy of the row to the new, don't bother with the `IF UPDATE()` junk. It will return true even if those values didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an AFTER update so by the time it runs Customers should aleady be updated. Change your logic to use deleted instead of core.customers and it should work

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comments (and as suggested by @RobertSheahan), you should use the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [core].[updCustomersSync] ON [core].[Customers]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    /*  You can omit the IF statement.  Just let the UPDATE statement below do all the work. */
    --IF ( UPDATE(Addr1)
    --     OR UPDATE(Addr2)
    --     OR UPDATE(Addr3)
    --     OR UPDATE(Zip)
    --     OR UPDATE(Contact1)
    --     OR UPDATE(Phone1)
    --     OR UPDATE(email)
    --     OR UPDATE(CustomerName)
    --   ) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE core.Customers
    SET SyncRequired = 1
    WHERE ID IN
    (
        SELECT i.ID
        --I will assume for this example that ID is unique.
        FROM INSERTED I
        JOIN DELETED d 
            ON d.ID = i.ID

        --Why all the NULL comparisons?  Well, presumably, if someone updates an existing value to NULL,
        --or an existing value is NULL and a new value is provided, you want to know.  Right?
        WHERE   d.[CustomerName] <> i.[CustomerName] OR (d.[CustomerName] IS NULL AND i.[CustomerName] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[CustomerName] IS NULL AND d.[CustomerName] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[Addr1] <> i.[Addr1] OR (d.[Addr1] IS NULL AND i.[Addr1] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[Addr1] IS NULL AND d.[Addr1] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[Addr2] <> i.[Addr2] OR (d.[Addr2] IS NULL AND i.[Addr2] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[Addr2] IS NULL AND d.[Addr2] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[Addr3] <> i.[Addr3] OR (d.[Addr3] IS NULL AND i.[Addr3] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[Addr3] IS NULL AND d.[Addr3] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[Zip] <> i.[Zip] OR (d.[Zip] IS NULL AND i.[Zip] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[Zip] IS NULL AND d.[Zip] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[Contact1] <> i.[Contact1] OR (d.[Contact1] IS NULL AND i.[Contact1] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[Contact1] IS NULL AND d.[Contact1] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[Phone1] <> i.[Phone1] OR (d.[Phone1] IS NULL AND i.[Phone1] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[Phone1] IS NULL AND d.[Phone1] IS NOT NULL)
        OR d.[email] <> i.[email] OR (d.[email] IS NULL AND i.[email] IS NOT NULL) OR (i.[email] IS NULL AND d.[email] IS NOT NULL)
    )
END
```